# Polling directory on File Server

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, .net-4.0, filesystems

I need to write an application that polls a directory which contains images on a file server and display 4 at a time.

This application will be run up to 50 times across the network at the same time.

I'm trying to think of the best architecture to complete this requirement.

I was working on the idea of opening a file with read/write access and no file share allowed so that if another PC came in to read it it would error and it would have to move on to the next one, the problem is, is that I need to access all 4 images in sequence on the same pc ensuring other pc's dont try to open them. So for example if PC1 tries to open 1.jpg it needs to be able to open 1,2,3,4.jpg.  If another PC comes in at the same time to read them I need a way for it to then open 5,6,7,8.jpg and so on and so on.

It seems a simple requirement but a nightmare to try and build successfully.

Comment: Are the files in a /known/ sequence?  are they added as a group?

Comment: How are the files added to the directory?  Do you control that program/web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically dealing with a race condition here, and I don't see a way to handle it from separate instances of your application running on separate machines unless you can guarantee your file naming will always follow a standard naming convention that would allow you to work with the sequence of 4 files using only the name of the first.

The best way to handle this would be using a centralized resource to manage access to your files, either a database as was suggested in a comment or else a service (such as WCF) that would "hand out" each set of 4 files.

Comment: If I could get control of the file name what would you suggest?

Comment: @Jon I would still suggest using a centralized resource to control access. I think it's a better solution. Using file naming conventions would just make it *possible*, not necessarily *good*.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `1.jpg.lock` file?  The presence of a the file indicates the images are locked and any other instance of the application should skip that set.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a database which can atomicly control access to the files (or rather their associated record in the database), but that's a lot of work.

Comment: A lock file won't help with keeping other instances from opening one of the next sequential files, there will still be a race condition.